# Finding the real source of an exception thrown in angular.mock.exceptionHandlerProvider

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm trying to contribute to angularjs, and I've made a mistake somewhere.
In the console output of the karma unit tests, I see the following:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'then'
at /Users/me/dev/angular.js/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js:246
```

The line this error leads me to, is a line in `angular.mock.$ExceptionHandlerProvider.mode`, in the `rethrow` case. So, this thing is rethrowing an exception, but how do I know where it came from? I know it means I'm expecting a $q promise somewhere, but not getting one, but I want to know where in my code this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the try..catch to the place where it was thrown and print stack trace

```
try {
  // line 246 in angular-mocks.js
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.stack);
}
```

you could just wrap the whole file in try..catch to be sure that it catch the exception.